# VueX / Nuxt Store returns failed with status code 400

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios, vuex, nuxt.js

I'm having an issue with my store to get categories from an API, using Nuxt and Axios.  This is my request located in my index.js file, in my store folder.

```
export const state = () => ({
    categories: []
})

export const getters = {
    categories (state) {
        return state.categories
    }
}

export const mutations = {
    SET_CATEGORIES (state, categories) {
        state.categories = categories
    }
}

export const actions = {
    async nuxtServerInit({ commit }) {
        let response = await this.$axios.$get('categories')

        commit('SET_CATEGORIES', response.data)
    }
}
```

[This is the response I receive after Nuxt has built the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hsLYa.png)

Thanks and hope someone can help.

Comment: Did you try `let response = await this.$axios.get('categories')` instead of `let response = await this.$axios.$get('categories')`..
I removed $ in get method

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply.  I've just tried your suggestion and I'm starting to think it's something to do with my Nuxt config file.  I'm doing all the API stuff in Laravel using Homestead, and Nuxt for the front-end.  

In my modules in the config file I have this:
['@nuxtjs/axios',{baseURL: 'http:shift.test:8000/api'}],

I had to access my Nuxt app using the IP for Laravel, as localhost:8000 wasn't working as I'm running it through vagrant (Laravel Homestead).  

I think it has something to do with my baseURL, and my environment setup but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: Don't know if this helps, but when I send a get request to http://shift.test/api/categories in Postman the JSON data return's as expected, so that leads me to believe it's something to do with my store or my environment config.

Comment: EDIT: I've fixed it, realised in my baseURL, that I'd missed the two // after HTTP:, how embarrassing.  Thanks for the help regardless.